# Open different folders and sheets with certain name pattern?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA codes that allows me to select multiple excel file and based on the names of the file, it should import the data. for instance if there are two excel files with the same name prefix, like the name starts with N. it should open and import the data, however if the name prefix exists onces, it should neglect the file.
I write the following code to iterate through the collection of workbooks and extract the worksheets name, however in the it only iterates once in the second iteration, array out of range error displays. any suggestion or help is highly appreciated.

```
      Sub import()
Dim shName1 As Worksheet
Dim shName2 As Worksheet
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim FileName As String
Dim selectedBook As Workbook
Dim selectedBook2 As Workbook
Dim i As Byte  ''
Dim FileCnt As Long

'On Error GoTo Handle:
 ' Pick only excel files to import and allow multipleselection
 FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Select Workbook to Import", MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(FileToOpen) Then
        For FileCnt = LBound(FileToOpen) To UBound(FileToOpen)
            Set selectedBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileToOpen(FileCnt))
            Set shName1 = selectedBook.Worksheets(FileCnt)
            For i = FileCnt + 1 To UBound(FileToOpen) - 1
                Set shName2 = selectedBook.Worksheets(i)
                If shName1 <> shName2 Then
                    'do samething
                Else:
                    ' do otherthing
                MsgBox shName2.Name
            Next i '
        Next FileCnt '
    End If 'is Array
```

End Sub

the exile files looks like this:

1. TB Secure 20BV.xlsx
2. journal 20BV.xlsx
3. TB Secure 19BV.xlsx
4. journal 19BV.xlsx
5. TB Secure 21BV.xlsx
   i want only to follow the data with pair names like 20 or 19 but 21 is single thus i don't import it.each workbook has a single worksheet in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to iterate between workbooks and their worksheets, try using of the next code. If you need to do something with the sheets according to their name, please more accurately explain what you need...

```
Sub WorkbooksAndSheetsIteration()
  Dim FileToOpen As Variant, FileCnt As Long, sh As Worksheet, selectedBook As Workbook
  FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", _
                                    Title:="Select Workbook to Import", MultiSelect:=True)
        If IsArray(FileToOpen) Then
        For FileCnt = LBound(FileToOpen) To UBound(FileToOpen)
            Set selectedBook = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=FileToOpen(FileCnt))
            For Each sh In selectedBook.Sheets
                For shNo = 1 To selectedBook.Sheets.Count - 1
                    If left(sh.Name, 1) = left(selectedBook.Sheets(i).Name, 1) And _
                                                                  sh.Index <> i Then
                        boolOK = True: Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            If boolOK Then
                'do here the operation you need
                '...
            Else
                 selectedBook.Close False
            End If
            boolOK = False
        Next FileCnt
    End If
End Sub
```

For pairing workbooks according to the number before "BV.xlsx", please use the next code:

```
Sub WorkbooksAndSheetsIterationBis()
  Dim FileToOpen As Variant, FileCnt As Long, sh As Worksheet, selectedBook As Workbook
  Dim shNo As Long, boolOK As Boolean, i As Long, wName As Variant, strN As String, strN2 As String
  FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", _
                                    Title:="Select Workbook to Import", MultiSelect:=True)
        If IsArray(FileToOpen) Then
            For Each wName In FileToOpen
                strN = Split(wName, "BV.xlsx")(0)
                Debug.Print Right(strN, Len(strN) - InStrRev(strN, " ")): Stop
                For FileCnt = LBound(FileToOpen) To UBound(FileToOpen)
                    strN2 = Split(FileToOpen(FileCnt), "BV.xlsx")(0)
                    If Right(strN, Len(strN) - InStrRev(strN, " ")) = _
                            Right(strN2, Len(strN2) - InStrRev(strN2, " ")) Then
                            boolOK = True: Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If boolOK Then
                    Set selectedBook = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=FileToOpen(wName))
                    'do here the operation you need
                    '...
                End If
                boolOK = False
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ! what i want to do with the sheets is that to iterate in the fileToOpen array and based on the first letter of the sheets namecheck it against the second sheet if they have the same first name i can import all the data in the twee sheet. but if they first letter doesn't exists in the other files, then ignore the file, means don't import the data.

Comment: Are you talking about workbooks 'name prefix', or sheets 'name prefix'? In words you wrote something about the workbooks, in the code you try something related to the sheets name. Even if the way you do that is strange...  Can you clarify this aspect, please?

Comment: I am referring to the worksheets name. based on their name, i want to decide whether to import the data or not .

Comment: Ok. I will adapt the code according to my understanding, from this point of view...

Comment: @abraham foto: Adapted my answer code. Does it fit your need?

Comment: if i have sheets named as: sheet_1, sheet_2, sheet3,sheet4 and sheetLast. i should only import sheets with name heet_1, sheet_2, sheet3,sheet4, because they are couples but not sheetLast, because it is a single file

Comment: Glad to help you. Your code behaved in that way because you wrongly used `FileCnt` which was referring to the selected workbooks number. If the opened workbook had less sheets, it produced the error...

Comment: i encounter some problem because my file looks like this

Comment: How 'like this'? Did I miss a link or something? Besides that, I could now understood that in order to select the workbook for transfer, is it necessary to be more occurrences of names starting with the same letter? Do only the consecutive sheets to be checked, or a sheet against all the other?

Comment: @abraham foto: I've just adapted the code to check a sheet name against all the existing sheets.

Comment: @abraham foto: So, now I understand that you do not need the sheets name pairing. You need the workbooks name to be paired. Is that last understanding correct? But, please answer as soon as possible. I must live in about 10 minutes... And please clarify if in all the cases the workbook naming respect the rule of two digits numbers followed by "BV.xlsx". Is that assumption correct?

Comment: @abraham foto: The new code needs only the workbook name to fishes in "BV.xlsx". The identification number can be of whatever number of digits, if it is separated from the rest of the string name by space (" ").

Comment: Thanks the new code looks promising. you are right are workbook has a single sheet this sheet name  has similarity with the other sheets in different workbook then we import. we can consolidate the data from the two sheets. The idea is one is may be a balance sheet of 1999 and the second the bank account in 1999 then we import both sheets and consolidate the data. if there is a sheet balance for 2000 but there is no sheet for bank accounts for 2000 then we dont import the data.

Comment: @targetRange2: Yes, it should work. Of course, if I correctly understood your need... I tested for three such workbooks. But, I would like to emphasize that what you said in your last comments had to be told form beginning, in your answer... Now, I must prevent you that the code find the occurrence of such a pair, but, I I well understood your need, it has to open both files and skip the second one for the next iterations. Not very complicated (neither so simple), but impossible to be solved without knowing what is about...